# LXX Job 39:20 "snort" vs "breast"

Tags: septuagint, job

How did the translators of the LXX out of the Hebrew text of Job 39:20 decide to use the word "breast" where the Hebrew text (Stuttgarsenia) has the Hebrew word "snort" (Brown Driver Briggs 637b)?

Comment: Welcome to BH. Please take a moment to take the Tour and see the Help (below) to see how the the site works. As it stands, you are actually asking a matter of opinion 'How did (they) decide ?' which only 'they' could divulge. I suggest you edit the question so that you are asking for a factual answer rather than an unproveable opinion of an historic decision.

Comment: This is, perhaps, another example where the text of the LXX and BHS differ - there are numerous such examples - some involving numerous added verses etc.

Answer (score 1):

Hebrew:

[image]

LXX:

[image]

As explained in [Style and Context of Old Greek Job](https://books.google.be/books?id=iGZjDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA254&lpg=PA254&dq=%CF%80%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%B9%CE%AD%CE%B8%CE%B7%CE%BA%CE%B1%CF%82%20%CE%B4%E1%BD%B2%20%CE%B1%E1%BD%90%CF%84%E1%BF%B7%20%CF%80%CE%B1%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%80%CE%BB%CE%AF%CE%B1%CE%BD,%20%CE%B4%CF%8C%CE%BE%CE%B1%CE%BD%20%CE%B4%E1%BD%B2%20%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%B8%CE%AD%CF%89%CE%BD%20%CE%B1%E1%BD%90%CF%84%CE%BF%E1%BF%A6%20%CF%84%CF%8C%CE%BB%CE%BC%E1%BF%83&source=bl&ots=8m0vZG4a5U&sig=ACfU3U1iRGfnRztg65EwVU3UZ3i1jkqFFw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1uq-JiKTpAhUOyqQKHV-ABQUQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=snort&f=false)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your answer is confusing. I do see in your reference a discussion on the LXX choice of translation for v. 20, but I still don't see a clear answer to the OP's question; namely, why they choose to translate נחרו into breast? Is this due to a variant text, or something else? Please elaborate

Comment: It literally says "one could speculate the translator had difficulty interpreting the Hebrew,...the translator continued the thought of v19...the symmetrical contruction is retained".